# GNUstep: scanf does not accept char

Tags: char, scanf, gnustep

I have decided to try out Objective C. Since I do not have a Mac laptop, I have installed GNUStep on my computer. And from the very beginning, I have the following issue.

Code:

```
// First program

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
char nameC[50];
NSLog(@"ENter your name: ");
scanf("%c", &nameC);
NSLog(@"Name is: %c", nameC);
[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: problem with GNUstep]

Tried unichar, same thing. Does anyone know what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: NSLog(@"Name is: %s", nameC);

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused by the fact that `nameC` is a `char` array, and thus you use `%c` in `scanf` and `NSLog`. As Igor Tupitsyn commented, you should use `%s` - but in both functions.

Note however that [using `scanf` is in most cases a bad idea](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html); it's better to use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`.